# "Unable to initialise extensions" error while building maven project with "wagon-ssh"

Tags: maven, maven-wagon-plugin, wagon, maven-extension

Getting below error when building Maven (version 2.2.1) Project with wagon-ssh extention

pom.xml:

```
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

> Unable to initialise extensions
>   Component descriptor role: 'com.jcraft.jsch.UIKeyboardInteractive', 
>   implementation: 'org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.jsch.interactive.PrompterUIKeyboardInteractive', role hint: 'default' has a hint, but there are other implementations that don't

any suggestions/hints is very much appriciated.

Answer (score 9):

try installing maven3 version ..!!

Comment: Wagon doesn't seem to work with maven version 2.2.1. I upgraded to 3.1.1 and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with Maven 2.X.X by downgrading the version of wagon-ssh to be 1.0:

```
<build>
   ...
   <extensions>
      <extension>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
         <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
         <!-- version 1.0 seems to work with maven 2.X.X -->
         <version>1.0</version>
      </extension>
   </extensions>
</build>
```

As an aside, I had problems with 1.0 (and the latest wagon-ssh versions) using maven version 3.2.1 and the `scp:` repository URLs.  When downloading from the repo, small files would hang at the end.   I switched to using `sftp:` URL and everything seems to be working better.